# Basic Abstract Algebra - Subgroups of Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group of order 72. Show that $G$ has exactly one subgroup of order 8.

I know by theorem that $G$ must have at least one subgroup of order 8, but I'm having trouble showing it has only one.

I know that it is necessary to use the prime decomposition theorem, but I'm having trouble understanding how finding the isomorphism classes of $G$ will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the [classification theorem of finite abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group), the group is isomorphic to $G \times H$ where $G$ and $H$ are groups of orders $8$ and $9$, respectively.

From here, we can prove that $(g,h) \in G \times H$ has order dividing $8$ only if $h=\mathrm{id}_H$.  This implies that $G \times \{\mathrm{id}_H\}$ is the only subgroup of order $8$.

Comment: Are you sure that the classification theorem implies this? What if our group is isomorphic to $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_9$ instead?

Comment: Then $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_9$.

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying. Alright, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Navid (How is the classification theorem for finite abelian groups less of a hammer than Sylow?)

Comment: @Pedro, It's just easier for me to understand because we haven't covered anything to do with Sylow. I don't really understand what 2-Sylow or 2-torsion or "normal of order 8" means. But I sincerely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

$72=8\times 9$. The $2$-Sylow subgroup is normal of order $2^3=8$, so it is unique.

**ADD** (Credits to [anon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11763/anon)) *Hint*  Suppose $N$ and $M$ are distinct subgroups of size $2^3$. Then $NM$ is $2$-torsion so it is also a $2$-subgroup; what can its size be?

Comment: Thank you, but we haven't covered Sylow subgroups. Is there a way to do this without relying on the Sylow theorems?